# Creating an interface for generation of SQL Statements in C#

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a neater way of doing the following with a LINQ type interface or any other for that matter. I usually use NHibenate but due to the dynamic nature of the system I am building I need to do the following.

```
StringBuilder select = new StringBuilder("select ");
select.Append("Column1, ");
select.Append("Column2, ");
select.Append("Column3 ");
select.Append("from TableName tn");
select.AppendFormat("where tn.Column1 = {0}", 12);

DataSet dataSet = select.ExecuteSelect() // is an extension method that takes a string builder
```

All string values come from a MetaColumn and MetaTable meta store which allows me to construct the statments. Fortunitly they are fairly simple. No joins, just INSERTS and UPDATES. There are up to 50 different tables with columns ranging 100+-. I would like to be able to do something like

```
string statement = select allColumns from new TableName<"TableName">() where UniqueKey<"Column1">(12);
```

Something like this ... any ideas???

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could create your own static class that encapsulates the process of creating the statements and use them i.e. like this: `SQLCreator.CreateSelect(new List<String>() { "ColumnToSelect" }, "TableToSelectFrom", "SampleColumn < 10");`

Comment: +1. Cool idea, it seems a little loosely typed though.

Comment: @Lucas ... I could prob use a bunch of extensions to control the interface.

Comment: @Lucas think youre right there is no nice way of "hiding this" it just gives me that bad feeling.

Comment: It's good you want to hide SQL building code, you can create some nice reusable classes doing it :). Implementing it to handle linq syntax can be harder to achieve to make it work efficiently, using some statement building classes/extension methods is easy and quite intuitive.

Comment: Only thing I can add to this is that you should always include a Where 0=0 so your clauses can always start with AND ... makes it more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some micro ORM. [Simple Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) should play well for you